# Deleting multiple with PDO and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, pdo

Having an issue with my current script. I am using PDO and ajax to delete a record. I call the images via mysql with PDO using the below code:

```
<?php 
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM img_slider ORDER BY id ');
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo "
<li id='{$row['id']}'>
<div class='imgHover'>
<div class='hover'>
<a href='delete.php?id={$row['id']}' class='deleteitem' ><img src='../img/delete.png'></a></div>
<img src='{$row['path']}'>
</div>
</li>";
}
```

I use this javascript to send the ID and to `delete.php` and also remove the image thumbnail from the list:

```
$(function() {
  $('.deleteitem').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).parent('li').attr('id');
    $.get('delete.php',{ id: id}).done(function(data) {
      if(data=='Error, insert query failed') {
          // dont delete from list
          alert('Failed to delete '+id);
      } else {
          //delete from list
          $('#'+id).remove();
          alert('Deleted '+id);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I have multiple records from different rows I wish to delete, So i use the following PDO code to execute the deletion:

```
require("common.php"); 
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) { header("Location: login.php"); die("Redirecting to login.php"); } 

$id = $_GET['id'];

$pdo->beginTransaction();
$st = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM img_nav WHERE id = :id');
$st->execute(array(':id', $id));
$st = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM img_slider WHERE id = :id');
$st->execute(array(':id', $id));
$st = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM img_landing WHERE id = :id');
$pdo->commit();
```

I have tried linking directly to the `delete.php` and not going through the javascript, chrome simple gives me a server error. Am I doing everything right here? I am only a beginner and English not so good any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: First of all, requests that alter data **should never be GETs**, use `POST`. (Heard of pre-fetching browsers? they exist... They will delete the lot..). If chrome gives you a server error, the script encountered a fatal error somewhere. To _know_ which error, see the [_"I have a typical "does not work" problem."_ answer in the tag-wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info).

Comment: @Wrikken Thank you for helping me define the error itself. I have found the error to be on line 11 and I am getting the `Call to a member function beginTransaction() on a non-object`I will google around, any advice to this error though?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't create a PDO object `$pdo`.

Comment: It's called `$db` in another script... Did you mean that object?

Comment: @Wrikken used `$db` and got a `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens` error, still trying to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Well, that's the correct object then. Leaves us with this: `array(':id', $id)` should be `array(':id' => $id)`